# Not Able To Deserialize the JSON response to Arrya Of Objects

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson

I am working on a code which consume the json and convert it to Objects .
For example say my json response is as below :-

String carJson ="{\"car\" : [{ \"brand\" : \"Mercedes\", \"doors\" : 5 },{ \"brand\" : \"Tata\", \"doors\" : 4 }] }";

Its array of car actually .

I have written below code to deserialize it to Java Objects :-

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

            List<Car> jsonToCarList = objectMapper.readValue(carJson, new TypeReference<List<Car>>() {}); 
            jsonToCarList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This is mine Car Class :-

```
public class Car {        
            @JsonProperty("car")
            private List<CarType> car;

        public Car(@JsonProperty("car") List<CarType> car) {
            this.car = car;
        }

        @JsonProperty("car")
        public List<CarType> getCar() {
            return car;
        } }
```

CarType is as below :-

```
class CarType {

@JsonProperty("brand")
private String brand;

@JsonProperty("doors")
private String doors;

public CarType(String brand, String doors) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.doors = doors;
}

public CarType() {

}

@JsonProperty("brand")
public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
}

@JsonProperty("doors")
public String getDoors() {
    return doors;
}
}
```

What's wrong here i am not getting . I am getting below error :-

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: {"car" : [{ "brand" : "Mercedes", "doors" : 5 },{ "brand" : "Tata", "doors" : 4 }] }; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:762)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:758)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:275)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:216)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:206)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3066)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2168)
```

Comment: What's the actual issue? Are you getting an error? Are fields null? You haven't actually told us what the problem is.

Comment: yes i am getting the error . I have updated the question . sorry i missed that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to deserialize into the wrong type:

```
List<Car> jsonToCarList = objectMapper.readValue(carJson, new TypeReference<List<Car>>() {});
```

should be

```
Car jsonToCar = objectMapper.readValue(carJson, Car.class);
```

The *List* you want is in the Car class you posted.